# How to write a keyDown and keyUp for webdriver?

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write a keyDown and keyUp for webdriver, similar to selenium. I know how to use Actions, but dint find a way to write a generic(working for special and normal keys) keyDown function.

Something like selenium which accepts keycode as well keys. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the JavaDoc for KeyUpAction and KeyDownAction in org.openqa.selenium.interactions:

- http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/package-summary.html

Moved to GitHub:

- http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/

See also:

- [How can I programmatically generate keypress events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169598/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events)

Comment: Link is broken :-/

Comment: I think broken links are one of the main reasons why answers are supposed to include actual steps instead of simply posting a link.

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to, for example, to select all from a input field and Delete, you can do something like this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.DELETE).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

**KeyDown and KeyUp**  -- Used to press a key and then un press the key.
Like below we can use this scenario;

```
Actions ac  = Actions(driverObj);
ac.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(we).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

Here we are using press CONTROL key and then click() and then unpress the CONTROL key.