# How can I programmatically generate keypress events?

Tags: java, keyboard, awt, system, awtrobot

What the java program should do is it should trigger keyboard press on some condition without a person pressing a keyboard key. So any program running in windows and in focus which requires keyboard input will get the input without a person actually pressing the keyboard.

I found these related questions here :
[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574850/trigger-a-keyboard-key-press-event-without-pressing-the-key-from-keyboard),
[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c)

I was wondering if there is any method to do this in Java.

Comment: Please visit this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745959/how-to-simulate-keyboard-presses-in-java

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.

Code snippet:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.KeyEvent;

Robot r = new Robot();
int keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_A; // the A key
r.keyPress(keyCode);
// later...
r.keyRelease(keyCode);
```

However, if you are trying to automate a task on your computer, I would recommend [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com). It's dedicated to automating common tasks, so it would be easier to use it instead of Java.