# Sending KeyPress Events with Java Robot to print something from browser in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to automate a web browser, but I have a test case in which I need to save a pdf. Inspired by the methods employed in these two questions [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169598/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events)
[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745959/how-to-simulate-keyboard-presses-in-java) I have got the "Save As" to pop up with a java Robot object and pressed control + s by:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

This works great; however, when I try to type a location in the save to box and press enter with this code:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

it doesn't do anything. How come I can't type POC in the save to box and press enter using the same technique when it clearly has the focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was happening was that the robot was moving too fast for the browser. I added some `robot.delay(x)`s and I changed the keyPress and keyRelease calls around a little bit. Here is the working code:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(3000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.delay(1000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
robot.delay(50);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```